# Comma, ')',or valid expression continuation expected

Tags: vb.net, text

I need my VB.net to write a file containing the following line

```
objWriter.WriteLine ("TEXTA " (FILEA) " TEXTB")
```

Unfortunatly the variable (`FILEA`) is causing problems i now get the error

> Comma, ')', or valid expression continuation expected.

Could someone explain this please?

Comment: If one of our answers solved your problem, please accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You're not concatenating (joining) the strings proerly...

```
objWriter.WriteLine ("TEXTA " & FILEA & " TEXTB")
```

A better style to get into the habit of using is:

```
objWriter.WriteLine (string.format("TEXTA {0} TEXTB", FILEA))
```

The `FILEA` variable replaces the `{0}` placeholder in the format string. Depending on what the writer you're using is, you may have a formatted overload so you could just do:

```
objWriter.WriteLine ("TEXTA {0} TEXTB", FILEA)
```

And since you asked for an explanation;

The compiler is asking you what exactly you want it to do - you've given it 3 variables (String, variable, String) and haven't told it that you want to join them together - It's saying that after the first string `"TEXTA"`, there should either be the closing bracket (to end the method call), a comma (to pass another parameter to the method) OR a "valid continuation expression" - ie something that tells it what to do with the next bit. in this case, you want a continuation expression, specifically an ampersand to signify "concatenate with the next 'thing'".

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you're looking for [string concatenation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfx50zyk%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)? Try this:

```
objWriter.WriteLine("TEXTA" & FILEA & "TEXTB");
```

Note that `FILEA` isn't exactly a conventional variable name... which leads me to suspect there may be something else you're trying to achieve. Could you give more details?

Comment: Well this got rid of my error thanks Im actually witing a line of text and need to put the name of a file collected in another text file within the new text file between the two standard bits of text.